# Hoping rebus #27 isn't boring

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Either the singular or the plural is an acceptable answer.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't find this boring!

Comment: @El-Guest:  With the exception of the investigator one, I'm never sure if mine are too easy.  So, yes, it means a LOT! :)

Comment: Wordster, I'm glad to hear that! I loved the investigator one a lot too, that was very amusing! :)

Comment: @Wordster For what it's worth, I think most of the time I solve them within a few seconds. (Also, most of the time someone else has already solved them.)

Comment: We honestly need more rebus puzzles. These are just too funny!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this

> MANDRILL/MANDRILLS, a type of monkey?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is!